# how to get the exact page of searchlist in Youtube api V3?

Tags: youtube-api

As you know use, i can use Optional parameters:

- `pageToken` to get nextPageToken or
- `prevPageToken`

but how can i get the exact page, like page4? [Link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#pageToken)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to jump ahead through results as in web page. You need to iterate through pages.